# ES6 import happening before .env import

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Trying to use an environment variable from my dotenv file crashes my app because it seems the dotenv file is not loaded on time.

```
// server.js
require('dotenv').config({ silent: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' })
console.log("Here is the env var: ", process.env.SPARKPOST_API_KEY) // works
import express from 'express'
import routes from './routes'
(...)
app.use('/api', routes);

// routes/index.js
import somecontroller from '../controllers/somecontroller'
const routes = express.Router()
routes.use('/somecontroller', somecontroller)

// somecontroller.js
import sendEmail from '../helpers/sparkpost'

// ./helpers/sparkpost.js
import SparkPost from 'sparkpost'
var sparky = new SparkPost()  // uses process.env.SPARKPOST_API_KEY
export default function sendEmail() {
}
```

crashes with error

```
Error: Client requires an API Key.
```

The API key is there, so it seems that sparkpost.js is instantiating `new SparkPost()` before the `dotenv` file gets loaded.

How do I work around this?

Comment: Please don't downvote a serious question.

Comment: Move whatever is trying to access the env var into a callback that you call, rather than something that runs immediately when imported.

Comment: The question beign serious/not serious has nothing to do with the downvote.

Comment: @KevinB so why the downvote?

Comment: The question doesn't include enough information to recreate the problem.

Comment: You don't even show where you import somecontroller.js.

Comment: @idbehold that's because I'm not even importing it. I'll add that

Comment: @softcode then your question makes no sense, because if you aren't importing it it isn't running and therefore couldn't possibly be getting instantiated at all.

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. How is it throwing an error if you're not even importing that file?

Comment: @idbehold Really sorry, you guys are right I am importing it in a controller. Updated

Comment: all Imports run before code, regardless of where in the code they are.

Comment: @KevinB So shouldn't `require('dotenv').config({ silent: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' })` happen before `new SparkPost()`?

Comment: is that what appears to be happening in your case? doesn't seem so.

Comment: @KevinB yes, I am requiring dotenv at the top of my server.js file, and `new SparkPost`, which requires env var, crashes the app

Comment: The solution regardless is in my first comment. control the execution of the code yourself.

Comment: @KevinB but if I include it in a callback, will it not instantiate `SparkPost` once for every callback execution ?

Comment: I mean, if you code it to do so yes. but putting it in a callback alone won't do that.

Comment: @KevinB you are referring to something like `import SparkPost from 'sparkpost' 
export default function startSparkPost() { new SparkPost() (...) }`, correct?

Comment: Yes. but if you wanted to ensure it only gets instantiated once, you do have the power to change the code such that it accomplishes that goal while still returning a function that can be called to get the ball rolling.

Comment: @KevinB But not the knowledge. Also you said "imports run before code" so why does importing `sparkpost.js` (my file) happen before importing `dotenv`?

Comment: `require` is not the same as `import`. `import`s are hoisted (as Tamas wrote in his answer below). `require` is a normal function call and is not hoisted (that wouldn't even make sense). (There does exist a stage 3 [dynamic `import()` proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import), so `require`-style imports should be available soon—and [already are](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-dynamic-import/) if you use Babel and Webpack.)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

My previous solutions don't work well at most organizations, because tools that rearrange imports like [`prettier`](https://prettier.io/) or [ESLint `sort-imports`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/sort-imports) will break the carefully handcrafted import order. Instead of continuously fighting the never-ending stream of new tooling, as of 2023, I suggest making these imports imperative using the [`import` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import).

```
// bootstrap.ts <- this is your entrypoint
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({ silent: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' });
await import('./server');

// server.ts
import express from 'express';
import SparkPost from 'sparkpost';
const sparky = new SparkPost();
...
```

In case you don't have access to top-level awaits for some reason, you can try these alternatives:

```
import('./server').catch(console.error);
// or
require('./server');
```

**Original answers**

Javascript `import`s are hoisted (but not Typescript!), so imported modules will initialize before any of the current modules initialization code gets to run. Fortunately imported modules are initialized in order, so a possible workaround is putting the config code in its own module:

```
// main.js <- make this your entry point
import "./config";
import "./server";

// config.js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({ silent: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' });

// server.js
import express from 'express';
import SparkPost from 'sparkpost';
const sparky = new SparkPost();
...
```

Or even simpler:

```
// config.js
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config({ silent: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' });

// server.js <- make this your entry point
import './config';
import express from 'express';
import SparkPost from 'sparkpost';
const sparky = new SparkPost();
...
```

**Typescript does not hoist imports**

The Typescript compiler currently does not hoist imports, so you could initialize `dotenv` right in the entry point `.ts` file, so your example in the question would just work. Linter tools tend to reject it and auto-formatting tools tend to break it tough, it is a fragile approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But then how do I use `sparky` in another file ?

Comment: @softcode the same way you do it now. This setup ensures that the config code runs before any other code of your application. Whereever you are using sparkpost, `SPARKPOST_API_KEY` will be already set up.

Comment: That is actually the way my server is currently set up, minus the `./config` which doesn't exist

Comment: `dotenv.config` is in my main entry point before `var app = express()`

Comment: @softcode config.js is an essential part here. That ensures that the config hapens before SparkPost's own initialization code.

Comment: I'm confused. I don't have anything to put into config.js.

Comment: @softcode My answer is the same, put the `dotenv.config()` call in a spearate file. Also, you still didn't tell us how do you import `somecontroller`. Are you using `express-controller`?

Comment: Ok, I'd just like to understand what is going on before making such a change to my app. Why is the import for dotenv not happening before the import of somecontroller.js?

Comment: Edited with the import of somecontroller.js. It's imported way after dotenv in the main entry point.

Comment: In your original code you dont import dotenv, you explicitly require it, which will always happen after the imports if they are in the same file, no matter what you do. Second, it's not importing dotenv that does the magic but caling `dotenv.config`, which is by no means an import statement, so still, runs after imports. And by the way I still dont see where you import somecontroller, only where you use it, but it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Thanks for aha moment. Will create config.js. Just to make sure I understand, hypothetically if I changed all imports to requires it would work?

Comment: @softcode Much better now :) So you see, importing routes (thus importing somecontroller, thus importing sparkhost) happens before you `require('dotenv')`. `require('dotenv')` is an expression, not an import statement. And yes, using only requires would work just right, but I really dont recommend that.

Comment: Thanks so much dude! Great explanation

Comment: Now we're talkin :)

Comment: @softcode I know I am late, but there is an even simpler solution where you dont have to change your entry point. Edited answer

Comment: I'd like this twice if I could.

Comment: That's an amazing solution for an issue of such importance in an API-enabled world I am surprised there are not more up-votes on this answer. This is required especially for testing and it helped simplify my firebase testing, a lot! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: I couldn't get this to work until I added my file to `.prettierignore` so that I could keep the imports in the order that they needed to be. +1 though because at least I finally got it working.

Comment: @Ryan That's a good point, I've run into that problem recently. I have updated my answer with the solution that I ended up using.

Comment: I love it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the `env` file to **occur first**,
and that we can only read once in the entire application,
as was possible in `commonjs` with `require`

In particular, in case you want to change the config, such as changing the PATH like this:
`config({ path: '../.env' })`

You must write a separate file, like this:

```
// env.js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config({ path: '../.env' });
```

Then import the `env.js` file in the main file like this:

```
// index.js
/** Import first before calling other files */
import './env.js';
import sqlConnect from './sql'
import express from 'express';

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

app.listen(PORT,()=>{
  console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`);
})
```

**Note!**
Import first before calling other files in the application.

Since in ES6 the `import` is performed before the code is executed.
You can see more here:
https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/

source:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import