# How to access dotenv variables in other files

Tags: node.js, express, dotenv

I'm using the dotEnv package for my Node/Express server. I have the `.env` file in the root of my project. In the root I have a `src` folder where I import the package in my `app.js` file which is the entry point of my server like so: (`root/src/app.js`)

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();
```

This works fine and I can access it in the `app.js` without issue.

But I have a file called `config.js` in `root/src/config` that I also want to use the env variables. But when I use something like `process.env.DB_HOST` I get `undefined`. How can I use these env variables in this file (and subsequent files)? I managed to get it to work by using

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: `${__dirname}/../../.env` });
```

Is there an easier way to access the env variables without having to import the package with the correct path to the env in each file I want to use it in?

Comment: This could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42817956/470749