# Move from CommonJS to ESM's export/import

Tags: javascript, import, export, es6-modules

It might has been fully discussed but I can't find a perfect answer from either [here](https://formidable.com/blog/2021/node-esm-and-exports/) or [here](https://gist.github.com/sindresorhus/a39789f98801d908bbc7ff3ecc99d99c#how-can-i-move-my-commonjs-project-to-esm).

Basically

- CommonJS uses the `require('./xx')` syntax, while
- ESM uses the `import {stuff} from './xx'` syntax

Here is how I've been doing the `require` when using CommonJS

- `require('apackage')` or
- `require('./myfile')`

I.e., I don't need to *specify their extensions* for either case.

But moving to ESM import, the `import {stuff} from './myfile'` is giving me the error of:

`Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module`

In [here](https://formidable.com/blog/2021/node-esm-and-exports/) it shows how to move from CommonJS and do ESM import:

from

```
const colors = require("colors");         // Obj w/ all export fields
const { red, blue } = require("colors");  // Select fields from export obj
```

to

```
import colors from "colors";          // _Only_ `default` export (`{ green }`)
import { red, blue } from "colors";   // Other named exports
```

But is it possible for me not to specify their extensions for *my own files* as well? Otherwise,

- it will be inconsistent between importing 'apackage` or './myfile',
- lots of unnecessary work for me to add their extensions to my current imports
- and need to force me to change again if I decided to switch their extensions between `js` and `mjs`,

Comment: nodejs esm implementation is quite different, thats why you have to give full name of file. [here](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#differences-between-es-modules-and-commonjs) you can find difference. If you don't want extensions then you have to use module bundles & babel to achieve it.

Comment: If it IS the case, then OK, @bogdanoff. Hmm..., how about the `import "./config";` in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42817956/2125837, how is that possible?

Comment: they are using babel + webpack to achieve it.  Anyway if you are having problem with `dotenv` use this ```import 'dotenv/config'```