# Why my static class cannot read the enviroment variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

I am building a node.js program using ES6 standard.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react18es6",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "activedirectory": "^0.7.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "2.2.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development run-p server start",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production npm run server",    
    "server": "nodemon -r dotenv/config ./server/index.js",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "testServer":"cross-env NODE_ENV=development node -r dotenv/config ./server/index.js",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My .env.development:

```
DATABASE_CHARSET=utf8
```

My config.js:

```
export class dbConfig{
    static charset =process.env["DATABASE_CHARSET"];
}
```

My index.js:

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import {dbConfig} from './config.js';

dotenv.config({ path: '.env.'+process.env.NODE_ENV });
console.log(dbConfig);
console.log(process.env["DATABASE_CHARSET"])
```

I am using the following command to execute the code:

`npm run testServer`

The output of `index.js` is as the following:

```
[class dbConfig] {
  charset: undefined      
}
utf8
```

Why the `dbConfig.js` can not get the environment variable?

I have tried the [suggested solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817339/es6-import-happening-before-env-import), but unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: How many `env` files do you have in your project? You'll need to specify nodeenv variable before running npm command so it can read the corresponding file. Something like: `"test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha --reporter spec"`

Comment: I have only 1 env file whose name is .env.development.

Comment: Then you can run `"NODE_ENV=development && npm run testServer`. Did you see my answer?

Comment: Do not abuse `class` syntax when all you need is an object literal.

Comment: I have specified in my post, the suggested solution is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this on top of your `My config.js` file so it can read from `process.env`

```
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
```

Or

```
require('dotenv').config();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am inspired by Dream Bold, the config.js is changed as the following:

```
    import dotenv from 'dotenv';
    export default class dbConfig{
        static{
            dotenv.config({ path: '.env.'+process.env.NODE_ENV });
            this.charset =process.env["DATABASE_CHARSET"];              
        }
    }
```

It works.

Comment: Just import or require `dotenv` will work